Read-SQLTableData throws error while excecuting
Can you help me in correcting the syntax?
$TableNames = Read-SQLTableData 
                  -ServerInstance $SrcServer 
                  -DatabaseName $SrcDatabase 
                  -SchemaName "dbo" 
                  -TableName "EntityMapping.MappingType"

I'm getting this error

At line:4 char:15
... ableNames = Read-SQLTableData -ServerInstance $SrcServer -DatabaseNam ...
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Read-SqlTableData], ItemNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidObjectError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.ReadSqlTableData


It looks to be a strand name for a table with the dot and all. Are you sure it's really called that. Perhaps try to surround it in [] brakets

Could you try reading the table the following way?
$server = "tcp:thesqlservername.database.windows.net,1433"
$database = "testdb"
$adminName = "testuser01@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com"
$adminPassword = "TestPassword"
$connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User ID=$adminName;Password=$adminPassword;authentication=Active Directory Password;"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "dsPersonData"
$q = @"
SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] 
"@
$da = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($q, $connection)
$da.Fill($ds)
$dtPerson = $ds.Tables[0]

